# Best practice for property name if already in use

Tags: c#

I have a model named `Name` which should contain a `Name` property.

However, I cannot name my property the same as the model.

How should I then name it? I looked around and saw people recommending `NameObj`, is this the best practice?

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    public class Name
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Value is a common name for this case

Comment: @SaulMarquez Thought so, but don't really wanna use it ..

Comment: Stating the obvious, You can rename the model if you can, since its model, its use might be limited in the codebase.

Comment: Property should be more specific. If we have class called `Name` then property can be `FirstName`, `LastName`, `MiddleName`

Comment: You need to describe you situation.

Comment: @MatJ What should I rename it to? ``NameModel``? I'd still preferably edit the property name

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I could use ``Username`` but would like to respect the original property name.

Comment: Original property name means? Provide sample input and expected output currently your question is unclear to me

Answer (score 2):

**I think your class is named badly.**

---

What is its purpose? Is it the name of a customer (`CustomerName`)? Is it the name of a user (`UserName`)? Is it the common ancestor of the name classes (`BaseName`)? The property `Name` seems right, but the class name `Name` is not. Consider changing it to something better specified.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about what the best practice would be if ever.

Comment: @Matt The best practice is naming your class properly. You won't _like ever_ face this problem if you give expressive, properly qualified name to your classes and properties.